# Uploading to Google Drive API using Ruby RestClient

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-drive-api, rest-client

I'm trying to upload a small image file to Google Drive using RestClient.  I already have an access token (being requested in earlier code) but I am not sure how to form the payload.

The API docs state the request should look like this:

```
POST /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_file
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token

JPEG data
```

I have tried the following but it results in an error:

```
require 'rest-client'

file = File.open("./uploaded-by-api.jpg")
response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files', payload: { uploadType: "media", file: file,  }, headers: {  Authorization: "Bearer #{access_token}", "Content-Type" => "image/jpeg", "Content-Length" => "1000" })
```

I'm pretty sure there is a mistake in the way I'm including the actual file data but I can't find any examples of this with RestClient.

Answer (score 1):

Ok solved it with the following:

```
response = RestClient.post(
  'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files',
  { 'uploadType' => "media", 'upload' => file },
  "Authorization" => "Bearer #{access_token}",
  "Content-Type" => "image/jpeg",
  "Content-Length" => "1000"
)
```